# Queue.conf mongodb scheme

Tags: mongodb, asterisk

We are using [this](https://github.com/minoruta/ast_mongo) to integrate mongodb and asterisk.What kind of scheme should we use to be able to integrate queue.conf to mongodb ?

Answer (score 0):

Use odbc

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/odbc-connector-for-mongodb

Use usual scheme over odbc, should work just ok.